# libusb error when doing libusb_control_transfer

Tags: usb, webcam, libusb, libusb-1.0

I'm trying to control a USB webcam device by following what is mentioned on this thread: https://sourceforge.net/p/linux-uvc/mailman/message/35920367/. That thread says:

You can also send direct USB commands in C, allowing you to work around the firmware misbehaviour by ignoring the UVC spec. Something like:

```
memcpy(buf, "\x80\x01\xF1", 3);
ret = usb_control_msg(devh, USB_TYPE_CLASS + USB_RECIP_INTERFACE, 0x01, 0x0300, 0x0400, buf, 3, 1000);
```

My code looks like:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include "libusb.h"

int main(int argc, char **argv) {
    libusb_context *context = NULL;
    libusb_init(&context);

    libusb_device_handle *devh;
    devh = libusb_open_device_with_vid_pid(context, 0xa168, 0x0710);
    fprintf(stderr, "devh:%lu\n", (long unsigned)devh);

    libusb_detach_kernel_driver(devh, 0);
    libusb_claim_interface(devh, 0);

    char buf[3];
    memcpy(buf, "\x80\x01\xf1", 3);
    uint8_t bmReqType = 32 + 1;// the request type (direction of transfer)
    uint8_t bReq = 1;// the request field for this packet
    uint16_t wVal = 0x300;// the value field for this packet
    uint16_t wIndex = 0x400;// the index field for this packet

    int r = libusb_control_transfer(devh, bmReqType, bReq, wVal, wIndex, buf, 3, 1000);
    fprintf(stderr, "libusb_control_transfer returns %d\n", r);

    libusb_close(devh);
    libusb_exit(NULL);
}
```

I'm getting either LIBUSB_ERROR_IO (-1) or LIBUSB_ERROR_PIPE (-9).

The USB device is reported as:

```
Bus 001 Device 033: ID a168:0710 AnMo Electronics Corporation 
Device Descriptor:
  bLength                18
  bDescriptorType         1
  bcdUSB               2.00
  bDeviceClass          239 Miscellaneous Device
  bDeviceSubClass         2 
  bDeviceProtocol         1 Interface Association
  bMaxPacketSize0        64
  idVendor           0xa168 AnMo Electronics Corporation
  idProduct          0x0710 
  bcdDevice           24.14
  iManufacturer           2 AnMo Electronics Corporation
  iProduct                1 Dino-Lite Premier
  iSerial                 0 
  bNumConfigurations      1
  Configuration Descriptor:
    bLength                 9
    bDescriptorType         2
    wTotalLength       0x0239
    bNumInterfaces          2
    bConfigurationValue     1
    iConfiguration          0 
    bmAttributes         0x80
      (Bus Powered)
    MaxPower              500mA
    Interface Association:
      bLength                 8
      bDescriptorType        11
      bFirstInterface         0
      bInterfaceCount         2
      bFunctionClass         14 Video
      bFunctionSubClass       3 Video Interface Collection
      bFunctionProtocol       0 
      iFunction               5 Dino-Lite Premier
    Interface Descriptor:
      bLength                 9
      bDescriptorType         4
      bInterfaceNumber        0
      bAlternateSetting       0
      bNumEndpoints           1
      bInterfaceClass        14 Video
      bInterfaceSubClass      1 Video Control
      bInterfaceProtocol      0 
      iInterface              5 Dino-Lite Premier
      VideoControl Interface Descriptor:
        bLength                13
        bDescriptorType        36
        bDescriptorSubtype      1 (HEADER)
        bcdUVC               1.00
        wTotalLength       0x0067
        dwClockFrequency       15.000000MHz
        bInCollection           1
        baInterfaceNr( 0)       1
      VideoControl Interface Descriptor:
        bLength                 9
        bDescriptorType        36
        bDescriptorSubtype      3 (OUTPUT_TERMINAL)
        bTerminalID             2
        wTerminalType      0x0101 USB Streaming
        bAssocTerminal          0
        bSourceID               5
        iTerminal               0 
      VideoControl Interface Descriptor:
        bLength                26
        bDescriptorType        36
        bDescriptorSubtype      6 (EXTENSION_UNIT)
        bUnitID                 4
        guidExtensionCode         {28f03370-6311-4a2e-ba2c-6890eb334016}
        bNumControl             8
        bNrPins                 1
        baSourceID( 0)          3
        bControlSize            1
        bmControls( 0)       0x0f
        iExtension              0 
      VideoControl Interface Descriptor:
        bLength                26
        bDescriptorType        36
        bDescriptorSubtype      6 (EXTENSION_UNIT)
        bUnitID                 5
        guidExtensionCode         {2812ae3f-bcd7-4e11-a357-6f1edef7d61d}
        bNumControl             8
        bNrPins                 1
        baSourceID( 0)          4
        bControlSize            1
        bmControls( 0)       0xff
        iExtension              0 
      VideoControl Interface Descriptor:
        bLength                18
        bDescriptorType        36
        bDescriptorSubtype      2 (INPUT_TERMINAL)
        bTerminalID             1
        wTerminalType      0x0201 Camera Sensor
        bAssocTerminal          0
        iTerminal               0 
        wObjectiveFocalLengthMin      0
        wObjectiveFocalLengthMax      0
        wOcularFocalLength            0
        bControlSize                  3
        bmControls           0x00000000
      VideoControl Interface Descriptor:
        bLength                11
        bDescriptorType        36
        bDescriptorSubtype      5 (PROCESSING_UNIT)
      Warning: Descriptor too short
        bUnitID                 3
        bSourceID               1
        wMaxMultiplier          0
        bControlSize            2
        bmControls     0x0000072f
          Brightness
          Contrast
          Hue
          Saturation
          Gamma
          Backlight Compensation
          Gain
          Power Line Frequency
        iProcessing             0 
        bmVideoStandards     0x00
      Endpoint Descriptor:
        bLength                 7
        bDescriptorType         5
        bEndpointAddress     0x83  EP 3 IN
        bmAttributes            3
          Transfer Type            Interrupt
          Synch Type               None
          Usage Type               Data
        wMaxPacketSize     0x0010  1x 16 bytes
        bInterval               6
    Interface Descriptor:
      bLength                 9
      bDescriptorType         4
      bInterfaceNumber        1
      bAlternateSetting       0
      bNumEndpoints           0
      bInterfaceClass        14 Video
      bInterfaceSubClass      2 Video Streaming
      bInterfaceProtocol      0 
      iInterface              0 
      VideoStreaming Interface Descriptor:
        bLength                            14
        bDescriptorType                    36
        bDescriptorSubtype                  1 (INPUT_HEADER)
        bNumFormats                         1
        wTotalLength                   0x0143
        bEndPointAddress                  129
        bmInfo                              0
        bTerminalLink                       2
        bStillCaptureMethod                 2
        bTriggerSupport                     0
        bTriggerUsage                       0
        bControlSize                        1
        bmaControls( 0)                     0
      VideoStreaming Interface Descriptor:
        bLength                            27
        bDescriptorType                    36
        bDescriptorSubtype                  4 (FORMAT_UNCOMPRESSED)
        bFormatIndex                        1
        bNumFrameDescriptors                5
        guidFormat                            {32595559-0000-0010-8000-00aa00389b71}
        bBitsPerPixel                      16
        bDefaultFrameIndex                  1
        bAspectRatioX                       0
        bAspectRatioY                       0
        bmInterlaceFlags                 0x00
          Interlaced stream or variable: No
          Fields per frame: 2 fields
          Field 1 first: No
          Field pattern: Field 1 only
        bCopyProtect                        0
      VideoStreaming Interface Descriptor:
        bLength                            50
        bDescriptorType                    36
        bDescriptorSubtype                  5 (FRAME_UNCOMPRESSED)
        bFrameIndex                         1
        bmCapabilities                   0x00
          Still image unsupported
        wWidth                            640
        wHeight                           480
        dwMinBitRate                  3072000
        dwMaxBitRate                 18432000
        dwMaxVideoFrameBufferSize      614400
        dwDefaultFrameInterval         333333
        bFrameIntervalType                  6
        dwFrameInterval( 0)            333333
        dwFrameInterval( 1)            400000
        dwFrameInterval( 2)            500000
        dwFrameInterval( 3)            666666
        dwFrameInterval( 4)           1000000
        dwFrameInterval( 5)           2000000
      VideoStreaming Interface Descriptor:
        bLength                            50
        bDescriptorType                    36
        bDescriptorSubtype                  5 (FRAME_UNCOMPRESSED)
        bFrameIndex                         2
        bmCapabilities                   0x00
          Still image unsupported
        wWidth                            352
        wHeight                           288
        dwMinBitRate                  1013760
        dwMaxBitRate                  6082560
        dwMaxVideoFrameBufferSize      202752
        dwDefaultFrameInterval         333333
        bFrameIntervalType                  6
        dwFrameInterval( 0)            333333
        dwFrameInterval( 1)            400000
        dwFrameInterval( 2)            500000
        dwFrameInterval( 3)            666666
        dwFrameInterval( 4)           1000000
        dwFrameInterval( 5)           2000000
      VideoStreaming Interface Descriptor:
        bLength                            50
        bDescriptorType                    36
        bDescriptorSubtype                  5 (FRAME_UNCOMPRESSED)
        bFrameIndex                         3
        bmCapabilities                   0x00
          Still image unsupported
        wWidth                            320
        wHeight                           240
        dwMinBitRate                   768000
        dwMaxBitRate                  4608000
        dwMaxVideoFrameBufferSize      153600
        dwDefaultFrameInterval         333333
        bFrameIntervalType                  6
        dwFrameInterval( 0)            333333
        dwFrameInterval( 1)            400000
        dwFrameInterval( 2)            500000
        dwFrameInterval( 3)            666666
        dwFrameInterval( 4)           1000000
        dwFrameInterval( 5)           2000000
      VideoStreaming Interface Descriptor:
        bLength                            50
        bDescriptorType                    36
        bDescriptorSubtype                  5 (FRAME_UNCOMPRESSED)
        bFrameIndex                         4
        bmCapabilities                   0x00
          Still image unsupported
        wWidth                            176
        wHeight                           144
        dwMinBitRate                   253440
        dwMaxBitRate                  1520640
        dwMaxVideoFrameBufferSize       50688
        dwDefaultFrameInterval         333333
        bFrameIntervalType                  6
        dwFrameInterval( 0)            333333
        dwFrameInterval( 1)            400000
        dwFrameInterval( 2)            500000
        dwFrameInterval( 3)            666666
        dwFrameInterval( 4)           1000000
        dwFrameInterval( 5)           2000000
      VideoStreaming Interface Descriptor:
        bLength                            50
        bDescriptorType                    36
        bDescriptorSubtype                  5 (FRAME_UNCOMPRESSED)
        bFrameIndex                         5
        bmCapabilities                   0x00
          Still image unsupported
        wWidth                            160
        wHeight                           120
        dwMinBitRate                   192000
        dwMaxBitRate                  1152000
        dwMaxVideoFrameBufferSize       38400
        dwDefaultFrameInterval         333333
        bFrameIntervalType                  6
        dwFrameInterval( 0)            333333
        dwFrameInterval( 1)            400000
        dwFrameInterval( 2)            500000
        dwFrameInterval( 3)            666666
        dwFrameInterval( 4)           1000000
        dwFrameInterval( 5)           2000000
      VideoStreaming Interface Descriptor:
        bLength                            26
        bDescriptorType                    36
        bDescriptorSubtype                  3 (STILL_IMAGE_FRAME)
        bEndpointAddress                    0
        bNumImageSizePatterns               5
        wWidth( 0)                        640
        wHeight( 0)                       480
        wWidth( 1)                        352
        wHeight( 1)                       288
        wWidth( 2)                        320
        wHeight( 2)                       240
        wWidth( 3)                        176
        wHeight( 3)                       144
        wWidth( 4)                        160
        wHeight( 4)                       120
        bNumCompressionPatterns             0
      VideoStreaming Interface Descriptor:
        bLength                             6
        bDescriptorType                    36
        bDescriptorSubtype                 13 (COLORFORMAT)
        bColorPrimaries                     1 (BT.709,sRGB)
        bTransferCharacteristics            1 (BT.709)
        bMatrixCoefficients                 4 (SMPTE 170M (BT.601))
    Interface Descriptor:
      bLength                 9
      bDescriptorType         4
      bInterfaceNumber        1
      bAlternateSetting       1
      bNumEndpoints           1
      bInterfaceClass        14 Video
      bInterfaceSubClass      2 Video Streaming
      bInterfaceProtocol      0 
      iInterface              0 
      Endpoint Descriptor:
        bLength                 7
        bDescriptorType         5
        bEndpointAddress     0x81  EP 1 IN
        bmAttributes            5
          Transfer Type            Isochronous
          Synch Type               Asynchronous
          Usage Type               Data
        wMaxPacketSize     0x0080  1x 128 bytes
        bInterval               1
    Interface Descriptor:
      bLength                 9
      bDescriptorType         4
      bInterfaceNumber        1
      bAlternateSetting       2
      bNumEndpoints           1
      bInterfaceClass        14 Video
      bInterfaceSubClass      2 Video Streaming
      bInterfaceProtocol      0 
      iInterface              0 
      Endpoint Descriptor:
        bLength                 7
        bDescriptorType         5
        bEndpointAddress     0x81  EP 1 IN
        bmAttributes            5
          Transfer Type            Isochronous
          Synch Type               Asynchronous
          Usage Type               Data
        wMaxPacketSize     0x0100  1x 256 bytes
        bInterval               1
    Interface Descriptor:
      bLength                 9
      bDescriptorType         4
      bInterfaceNumber        1
      bAlternateSetting       3
      bNumEndpoints           1
      bInterfaceClass        14 Video
      bInterfaceSubClass      2 Video Streaming
      bInterfaceProtocol      0 
      iInterface              0 
      Endpoint Descriptor:
        bLength                 7
        bDescriptorType         5
        bEndpointAddress     0x81  EP 1 IN
        bmAttributes            5
          Transfer Type            Isochronous
          Synch Type               Asynchronous
          Usage Type               Data
        wMaxPacketSize     0x0320  1x 800 bytes
        bInterval               1
    Interface Descriptor:
      bLength                 9
      bDescriptorType         4
      bInterfaceNumber        1
      bAlternateSetting       4
      bNumEndpoints           1
      bInterfaceClass        14 Video
      bInterfaceSubClass      2 Video Streaming
      bInterfaceProtocol      0 
      iInterface              0 
      Endpoint Descriptor:
        bLength                 7
        bDescriptorType         5
        bEndpointAddress     0x81  EP 1 IN
        bmAttributes            5
          Transfer Type            Isochronous
          Synch Type               Asynchronous
          Usage Type               Data
        wMaxPacketSize     0x0b20  2x 800 bytes
        bInterval               1
    Interface Descriptor:
      bLength                 9
      bDescriptorType         4
      bInterfaceNumber        1
      bAlternateSetting       5
      bNumEndpoints           1
      bInterfaceClass        14 Video
      bInterfaceSubClass      2 Video Streaming
      bInterfaceProtocol      0 
      iInterface              0 
      Endpoint Descriptor:
        bLength                 7
        bDescriptorType         5
        bEndpointAddress     0x81  EP 1 IN
        bmAttributes            5
          Transfer Type            Isochronous
          Synch Type               Asynchronous
          Usage Type               Data
        wMaxPacketSize     0x1320  3x 800 bytes
        bInterval               1
    Interface Descriptor:
      bLength                 9
      bDescriptorType         4
      bInterfaceNumber        1
      bAlternateSetting       6
      bNumEndpoints           1
      bInterfaceClass        14 Video
      bInterfaceSubClass      2 Video Streaming
      bInterfaceProtocol      0 
      iInterface              0 
      Endpoint Descriptor:
        bLength                 7
        bDescriptorType         5
        bEndpointAddress     0x81  EP 1 IN
        bmAttributes            5
          Transfer Type            Isochronous
          Synch Type               Asynchronous
          Usage Type               Data
        wMaxPacketSize     0x1400  3x 1024 bytes
        bInterval               1
Device Qualifier (for other device speed):
  bLength                10
  bDescriptorType         6
  bcdUSB               2.00
  bDeviceClass          239 Miscellaneous Device
  bDeviceSubClass         2 
  bDeviceProtocol         1 Interface Association
  bMaxPacketSize0        64
  bNumConfigurations      1
Device Status:     0x0002
  (Bus Powered)
  Remote Wakeup Enabled
```

Any idea what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: Did you ever make any progress on this? I'm having the same issue -- pipe error in libusb when trying to do a control transfer. I'm looking at a wireshark packet that looks like this: https://i.imgur.com/rdwYvHW.png and in my code I did: `rc = libusb_control_transfer(lusb_dev_hndl, /* bRequestType */ 0x21, /* 'Request Code' in wireshark */ 0x22, /* value */ ACM_CTRL_DTR | ACM_CTRL_RTS, /* index */ 0, nullptr, /* length */ 0, 0);`  I have the verbose level set in libusb, but I don't see any log messages higher than "debug".

Comment: @RaleighL. Very sorry. I gave up on this and it didn't work. It was only for one device so it wasn't worth investing too much time.

Answer (score 0):

Sadly I don't own this device anymore so I cannot test your code.

It looks fine though, the length stuff is correct. My only suggestions from there would be:

1. running your code as root in case this is a simple permission issue
2. checking dmesg in case the kernel output some useful messages
3. debugging further by:

   - using a USB traffic analyzer (Wireshark works fairly well) though it's likely you won't see anything because the error happens in the kernel driver at TX
   - turning on some kernel debugging features and try to hook into the drivers to understand where the error comes from: https://www.kernel.org/doc/html/v4.18/dev-tools/kgdb.html, https://www.kernel.org/doc/html/v4.18/trace/events.html

Good luck with troubleshooting.

Comment: 1. Done. 2. Nothing. I have posted the question on uvc-devel mailing list. I have patched the kernel with the 2017 patch but I'm getting errors too: https://sourceforge.net/p/linux-uvc/mailman/message/37106933/